# Lazy loading Angular modules with Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, lazy-loading, oclazyload

I'm trying to get lazy-loaded Angular modules working with Webpack, but I'm having some difficulties. Webpack appears to generate the split point correctly, because I see a `1.bundle.js` getting created that contains the code for the child app, but I don't see any request for `1.bundle.js` when I load the page, and the child app doesn't initialize. The `console.log` never seems to fire, and it doesn't even appear to get to the point where `$oclazyload` would initialize the module.

There are a few points where I am confused.

1) Will webpack make the request to the server, or do I have to load the second bundle manually? (I've tried both, and neither works)

2) If I do need to load the bundles manually, in what order should they be loaded?

3) The third argument to `require.ensure` supposedly lets you control the name of the bundle, but the bundle is named `1.bundle.js` no matter what string I pass.

4) Why can't I step through the code inside the `require.ensure` block in the debugger? When I do so I end up looking at this in the Chrome source view:

```
undefined


/** WEBPACK FOOTER **
 ** 
 **/
```

(Code Below)

Main entry point code:

```
'use strict';

import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-ui-router';
import 'oclazyload';


angular.module('parentApp', [
  'ui.router',
])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', ($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) => {
    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }])

  .config(['$stateProvider', ($stateProvider) => {
    $stateProvider
      .state('child-app', {
        url: '/child-app',
        template: '<child-app></child-app>',
        resolve: {
          loadAppModule: ($q, $ocLazyLoad) => {
            return $q((resolve) => {
              require.ensure(['./child-app/app.js'], (require) => {
                let module = require('./child-app/app.js');
                console.log(module);
                $oclazyload.load({name: 'childApp'});
                resolve(module.controller);
              });
            })
          }
        },
        controller: function() {
        }
      })
  }]);
```

Child app:

```
'use strict';

import childAppTemplateURL from '../templates/child-app.html';
import childAppController from './controllers/childAppController';

export default angular.module('parentApp.childApp', [])

  .component('applicationListApp', {
      templateUrl: childAppTemplateURL,
      controller: childAppController
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was unrelated to the `require.ensure` implementation. It was caused by some weirdness in the way `ocLazyLoad` is packaged (https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/issues/179). The fix in my case was simple, I just added `'oc.lazyLoad'` to the module dependencies.

```
angular.module('parentApp', [
  'ui.router',
  'oc.lazyLoad'
])
```

To answer two of my own questions, Webpack does indeed make a request to the server for the bundle, and you do not have to manually load the bundle. One gotcha that really confused me: the `resolve` block will fail silently if it contains a promise that won't resolve. In my case `$ocLazyLoad.load()` was failing, but there was no indication of the failure. The only clue was that the state provider wasn't adding the `<child-app></child-app>` markup to the DOM, which meant that it was actually initializing the state.